# Were "Associated Planets" mentioned anywhere in Enderverse other than "Investment Counselor"?

Tags: enders-game

I wasn't able to find any references to "Associated planets" (Planets outside of/not fully affiliated with Starways Congress governance) outside of one line in "Investment Counselor" (Short story from "First Meetings" series, where Ender first meets Jane).

> Sorelledolce was one of the newer colonies, only a hundred years old, but its status as an associated planet meant that a lot of shady and unregulatable businesses migrated here...

Are there other mentions of "Associated planets" in Enderverse canon anywhere?

Enderverse's [Wiki](http://ansible.wikia.com/wiki/Associated_planet) entry has no sources listed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Authorized Ender Companion](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0765320622) has this entry ("Investment Counselor" is the only source given, but Card is credited as co-author):

> The term "Associated Planet" refers to human-settled planets in the galaxy that have not aligned themselves with the Starways Congress's Hundred Worlds.

It doesn't contain any further information, other than including "Associated Planets" in the Hundred Worlds list.

The phrase "associated planet" (or "associated planets") does not appear in any of the other Ender books, as far as Amazon's "Search Inside" can find.  It's also not used in any of the [Intergalactic Medicine Show](http://www.intergalacticmedicineshow.com/) Ender short-stories.